# Quasifree states vs Gaussian states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, terminology

Does anyone know the origin of the term "quasifree states" in algebraic formulation of QFT? As far as I am aware of, the definition is effectively equivalent to Gaussian states centred at zero (vanishing odd-point correlators) and the state is completely specified by its two-point correlators (see also this other post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/392069/motivation-for-the-definition-of-gaussian-states))

I talked it out with my PhD supervisor and he found that misleading (since in quantum optics, for instance, people hardly use the term quasifree as far as I am aware of), which I can understand. I personally have no issue with the terminology, but I see the point that Gaussian states are so standard and more common than quasifree state that I do not know why we need another term for it. Perhaps there was a more AQFT-specific reason for the term (e.g., what quasi- in quasifree refers to)?